# How can I catch the XYZ coordinates for a curved road?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes, texture-coordinates, vector-mapping, custom-attributes

I'm making a curved road made with *Geometry Nodes* but I'm not able to get the mapping right.

I kind of managed to get the X and the Y right, but I'm just not able to also get the Z right.

As you can see below, I used the *Store Named Attribute* node in Geometry Nodes to catch the right information.

### [image: This is what the geometry nodes look like]

### [image: Here you can see how the X information is pulled towards one corner]

### [image: It is mapped asymmetrical]

[image: How can I get all the 3 directions (XYZ) right?]

Does anyone have a hint about how to get this right?

Edit:
Following the suggestion above for the already existing topic, I have tried to reproduce this myself. I have added my own bezier curve with a quadrilateral as a profile for the 'curve to mesh' node.
I still seem to get the same problem.
Many thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have created a node system that gives the "Generated Coordinates" from "Texture Coordinate" in the shader editor.

Comment: Hi @Muzammil Thanks! Did you post this system somewhere.

To the moderators: Thanks for the link to the other similar question. I have tried this solution, but the exact same problem occurs: the texture is mapped asymmetrically.

Comment: Please be so kind and post your blend file. If you used exactly the example in the other answer (domain *Face Corners*!), the result should also fit. Maybe the error is somewhere else.

Comment: You did everything right, but as I already mentioned: You would have to set the **Attribute Domain** of the *Group Output* to **Face Corner**. The UVs of a mesh are in this case always boundary points of a face, and exactly these are described with the *Face Corners*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NUzD.jpg

Comment: @quellenform That actually works! :-D Thanks a lot Quellenform for pointing that out! Is there a way I can buy you a drink? :-)

Comment: @PieterLeon You are welcome! If you would like to support my work, I would be very happy about a small tip! Please use the information on my profile page: https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/145249/quellenform?tab=profile Thanks!

Comment: Done. Thanks again!

Comment: @PieterLeon Thank you very much!